# fancybox event beforeClose not firing

Tags: jquery, asp.net, fancybox

I am using jquery fancybox and i want to hide an iframe containing a pdf file right before the fancybox pops open (which is working fine) and then beforeClose of the fancybox I want to make the iframe visible again due to a z-index issue with the pdf iframe. My issue is that the beforeClose even doesn't seem to be firing. Here is the code I placed below the images and iframe.

```
<script src="http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/wp-content/themes/radial/jquery.fancybox.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

   var frame = document.getElementById('Frame');

   jQuery("#zoom_08").bind("click", function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         var ez = $('#zoom_08').data('elevateZoom');
           $.fancybox(ez.getGalleryList());
           frame.style.display = 'none';
           return false;
    });


    $.fancybox({
      beforeClose: function () {
       frame.style.display = '';
             }
    });
```

I'm still new to Jquery so I'm not sure I understand what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
<iframe id="Frame"  width="680" height="1000" runat="server" />
```

On Page_Load i do the following to set the iFrame's src

```
 Frame.Attributes.Add("src", "./Files/" + Request.QueryString["certfile"].ToString());
```

Comment: This is just a stab in the dark as I cant test right now but try changing `frame.style.display = '';` to `frame.style.display = 'block';` and see what happens.

Comment: @philreed I tried it, but I never even get to the beforeClose function as I've even tried to place an alert in there.

Comment: Is this `$.fancybox(ez.getGalleryList());` triggering properly?

Comment: @JFK Yes that is working properly.

Comment: and what is the purpose of this `frame.style.display = 'none';` and why is just after `$.fancybox()` ? ... I mean, isn't that action you want to do `afterClose`?

Comment: I'm hiding the frame because of an issue with the pdf document's z-index. The pdf doc remains on top of the fancy box. And I guess it doesn't matter if it's before or after close. I was just like the pdf doc to re-appear after the user is done with the fancybox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
jQuery("#zoom_08").bind("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var ez = $('#zoom_08').data('elevateZoom');
    jQuery.fancybox(ez.getGalleryList(), {
        beforeShow: function () {
            frame.style.display = 'none';
        },
        afterClose: function () {
            frame.style.display = ''; // or .display = "block"; ?
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

... and remove :

```
$.fancybox({
  beforeClose: function () {
   frame.style.display = '';
         }
});
```

because that `beforeClose` would be for a fancybox that is opening nothing.

Comment: Thanks JFK! Worked seamlessly!